# Error CS1583 intermittently appearing when building C#/WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have a C#/WPF project built on Visual Studio 2013 Professional for work.

This project was originally built on a Windows 10 platform, but has been moved to another computer running Windows 7.

I have found that the project can be successfully built when the program first opens, and I have chosen "clean solution" first.  After any change is made, an error appears (Note that I have removed the company name from the line):

> "CSC : error CS1583: 'd:[Removed company+project name]\obj\Debug\CSCB4E1285F65D54791A82C162F265D41AD.TMP' is not a valid Win32 resource file".

I have searched for solutions and a common thing suggested is that there may be problems with an `.ico` files. I completely removed my icon file from the project and it did not resolve the error.

The Microsoft information on this error is:

> "This error occurs when you specify a filename with the /win32res compiler option that is not a valid or correctly formatted Win32 resource file. In Visual Studio, the filename is specified in the Application pane of the Project Designer."  I've looked in the Application pane and I could not find any /win32res options...

The building process itself is prone to hanging - Stopping at different points.  I stop, clean solution, and rebuild which often gets a different result.

What could I do to better diagnose the error?  Are there any tools that allow me to see where something went wrong?

Is there something that I have overlooked?

Any input would be great.

Comment: I would say, delete the whole bin folder, then update the references to dlls if there is any. Try building then, it should work.

Comment: I deleted the bin folder on the start up project and then redid all of the references.  More of the same errors have popped up

Comment: it means there is some bug with the code which is causing the build to fail. does all of the errors have similar description? if there is something like "unable to find xyz", fix that error.

Comment: I've just used the repair option for Visual Studio and have just reopened the program.  I have clicked "clean solution" and then "rebuild solution".  The build was hanging for a while, so I've clicked "Cancel build".  There are other errors, but they change all the time - The only consistent error is the TMP file not being a valid win32 program.

Comment: close the w3wp.exe process, and then start build again. other than that, i can't think of anything that might help.

Comment: I just re-opened the project and clicked "clean" and then "build" - The build has become stuck with the prompt "The operation that you requested is taking longer than..."  I also noticed in the build log that a invalid win32 program error had occurred.

Comment: Okay so... I copied the files to an external drive and then copied them to the drive on my original computer.  Everything seems to be fine on the old computer which tells me that it is something on the new computer.  The new computer is something that work will eventually force me to go to [sigh] - Is there a way to see what is happening step by step during the build so that I might be able to pin-point what is going wrong?